# Day's Total Column in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, dax, powerbi

I'm struggling with what should be some simple DAX.

Given a 'Booking' Table:

- Date
- User
- Booking#

I want to create a column for the days total but I want it on the 'Booking' table.

Previously I had achieved this by putting the total on my Date table.
But I don't want to continue that pattern going forward.

The DAX for the total column on the date table:

- Sum = CALCULATE(SUM(Booking[Booking]), Booking[Date])

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to count the bookings you have.  You might try the DistinctCount DAX function over Booking[Booking#].  Then if you use the date from the date table it will automatically filter the booking numbers.